# RFT (rational functional tester)

Tags: c++, rft

can we test a c++ application like NEAT( national exchange for automated trading  using IBM rational Functional Tester (RFT)

Comment: "Q: Can I convert an AcmeCorp document into a TeX file using the Bass-o-matic file converter? A: Try it and see" -- http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. If you face some particular problem, please state it.

Answer (score 0):

The programming language doesn't really matter, the GUI framework is important. There is a list of supported technologies on the IBM website: [Supplement for supported software for Rational Functional Tester](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038243).

You can easily download a 30 day trial of Rational Functional Tester to try whether it suits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

what type of application it is ? It does not matter which platform you use to develop the app.

RFT is much convenient for windows (stand alone), web and forms based app.

You can use test object inspector to spy over the objects. If you find sufficient recognition properties, then you can attempt play back.

If all works as expected, with little customization on validations, you will be able to automate the app.